# Why is 'axios.get' returning a promise object?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I've been trying to use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) in order to check whether or not a user is authenticated server side (Node+Express+Passport).

If a user is authenticated, the server sends back a "Connected" string, else, it sends back a "Not connected" string.

```
Router.get('/isAuth', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(200).send('Connected');
    } else {
        return res.status(200).send('Not connected');
    }
});
```

I wrote a simple function to check the server's response:

```
function isAuth() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/endpoints/isAuth')
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data === "Connected") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

The function is supposed to return true if the user is connected, and vice-versa.

Now, when I try to log the the function's results in the console, this is what I get:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
  __proto__ : Promise
  [[PromiseStatus]] : "resolved"
  [[PromiseValue]] : false
```

As you can see, the value returned is a promise object, whereas the desired output would preferably be a "True" or "False".

Comment: Well it is  "Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js"
No suprise it returns promises

Comment: Hi @KyleSentient have you find out how to extract those data yet? I was having trouble with the same thing today, or have you found any alternatives there?

Comment: @IrfandyJip Hey there. I honestly have no Idea what I did or how I did it, but I eventually managed to work my way out of the issue. Here's how I did it, but mind you, my project involves NodeJS/Express as a backend and VueJS as a frontend, so, if you're not familiar with those, you might get a bit confused. Here's how I handled it on the server: [ExpressJS Backend](https://github.com/ghuenlee/M2_Freelance/blob/master/app/routes/admin/index.js#L62), here's how I did it client-side: [VueJS Login Component](https://github.com/ghuenlee/M2_Freelance_admin/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue#L52)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

isAuth does an async request which will take some time. therefore it cannot return true or false directly. it will instead return a promise that gets that boolean value. to access your boolean value, you have to treat your isAuth() function as a promise:

```
isAuth().then(isAuthenticated => console.log(isAuthenticated));
```

**Update:**

this code:

```
var test = isAuth();
```

will return the promise syncronously and won't wait for the reponse result

if you want to access the reponse of the promise, you need to use then:

```
test.then(value => ...);
```

if you really want to do a syncronous http request (blocks your app, untill the request is resolved) you can checkout https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request

but you actually don't want to use if it is not for test purpose only.

another thing you could consider is the use of  [async/await](https://codeforgeek.com/2017/02/asyncawait-function-officially-shipped-nodejs-7-6-0/) which comes with node 7.6  but you first should fully understand the concept of promises

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your solution though it returns exactly the same object. Besides, what I want to do is return a boolean value, not output the result to the console. But whenever I do something like return true or return false, the output is always undefined.

Comment: the console output was just an example on how to access the boolean value you're trying to access. the expression as a whole sure is still a promise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'll read up a bit more about promises to try and grasp the way they work and clear up some of my confusion. Thanks!